# Abstract classes and Pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, polymorphism, virtual

I have a class

// i want an abstract class.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    virtual void bar()=0;
};
```

// i want this abstract calss to be used all over the program :) to enjoy polymorphism.

```
class EatFoo
{
public:
    vector<Foo> fooV; // not working
    vector<Foo *> fooPV;
};
```

I get a compile time error that abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Yes its true but i really want or i want to learn :

how to make other programmers "have to - have to" implement some function and i donot want to use pointers in my programs. [i donot know why ? but i have that gut feeling..]

Is there some pattern or something that can help me.
With java it is all references and yup it is doable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want polymorphic behaviour for container items, you have no choice but to use pointers. To make your life as easy as possible, you should use smart pointers, such as `shared_ptr<Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your gut is right... partly...

You shouldn't use **raw pointers**:

```
class EatFoo
{
public:
    vector<shared_ptr<Foo> > fooV;
};
```

There's no way in C++ to have collections of abstract objects.