# Two different ways of deallocating vector of pointers - why doesn't one work?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've got a vector of pointers to structs. The first method to deallocate memory works fine, but the second gives a segmentation fault (core dumped) after it is executed. Why is that so? Both look correct to me. Using g++ to compile.

```
struct milkNode {
    int unitCost;
    int unitsAvail;
};

int main() {

    //previous code

    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        milkNode *cur = new milkNode;
        cur->unitCost = cost;
        cur->unitsAvail = avail;
        allNodes.push_back(cur);
    }


    //Method 1, works fine
    vector<milkNode*>::iterator iter;

    for (iter = allNodes.begin(); iter != allNodes.end(); ++iter) {
        delete *iter;
    }

    allNodes.clear();

    //Method 2, segmentation fault after execution. Compiles without errors.
    //Segmentation fault occurs just before the last "after" is printed

    /*
    vector<milkNode*>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = allNodes.begin(); iter != allNodes.end(); ++iter) {
        milkNode *delThis = allNodes.back();
        allNodes.pop_back();
        cout << "before" << endl;
        delete delThis; //Attempted to put this statement before pop_back, still seg fault.
        cout << "after" << endl;
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

Already browsed through a few stackoverflow posts like this one: [Deleting vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942706/c-deleting-vector-of-pointers), but they do not seem to answer my question.

Comment: You can store a vector of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) so you don't have to worry about a deallocation scheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some point `iter` will be referencing the last element in the list, and in the loop you pop that element and delete it. This invalidates the iterator, and you then have undefined behaviour - your subsequent test against `end()` and increment cannot be relied on.

Since you don't actually need the iterator it would be much easier to replace

```
for (iter = allNodes.begin(); iter != allNodes.end(); ++iter) {
```

with

```
while (!allNodes.empty()) {
```

which would avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at the wrong place, thinking it was a problem with my pointer deallocation.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a look at the "last" iteration of your loop:

`iter` equals `allNodes.end() - 1`. Then you `pop_back()` on `allNodes`, now `iter` equals `allNodes.end()`. Last we come back to the loop head where you increase `iter` which is now `allNodes.end() + 1`!

And this is where your loop fails.

Answer (score 3):

second should be:

```
while (!allNodes.empty()) {
    milkNode *delThis = allNodes.back();
    allNodes.pop_back();
    delete delThis;
}
```